# Mongodb database is not storing collections and documents persistently

Tags: database, mongodb, data-analysis

I'm having one problem in mongodb, whenever I restart mongodb in command prompt, databases are there but the collections and documents in that database is removed, could anyone help me with this please.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please go through all these links: [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [how to good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: How do you know the databases are there?

Comment: _"whenever I restart mongodb in command prompt,..."_ How are you restarting the MongoDB? How (and what) are you creating collections and documents? Also, see [MongoDB CRUD operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/crud/).